# Is it possible to set keyboard shortcuts for a video streaming website like Youtube?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, streaming, javascript, hotkeys, youtube

Youtube already offers a list of [keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7631406). What if I want to set a different shortcut, for example, `ctrl`+`shift`+`p` for Pause/Play? Can I use a Javascript library like [Mousetrap](https://craig.is/killing/mice) for the purpose? Then what should be the correct code to put after `function()` in order to execute the Pause/Play action?

P.S. I know there may be some Chrome extensions ([streamkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/streamkeys/ekpipjofdicppbepocohdlgenahaneen) for example) that can do the job. However, some of the streaming websites I often visit are not included in streamkeys' service.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ways to `SET` keyboard shortcuts... but:

find the "three bar" (`///` <- *horisontal bars*) menu in the upper left, click it so that you get the left side panel shown, scroll down to find "Help" and click it.

Now type "Keyboard shortcuts" in the search field and activate the lookup.

You should now see...

> To access the list of Keyboard shortcuts, go to your profile picture
> Profile, and select Keyboard Shortcuts Keyboard. You can also enter
> SHIFT+? on your keyboard. When you mouse over certain player buttons,
> you’ll see the relevant keyboard shortcut. For example, when you mouse
> over the full screen icon, you'll see 'Full screen (f),' indicating
> you can enter f to open full screen.

... and a list of keys and their effects just below.

Comment: Thanks. But I want a solution that can change the keyboard shortcuts and also works for other video streaming sites.